# Deleting the .deleted entry from Linux

Tags: linux, delete-file

I am facing, less memory exception, because of *some files or inode entries* those are taking the hard disk memory space, I think?

*du command is showing 1.4G*

*df command is showing 17G*

My hard disk is of **20G**, also  when I fired **lsof | grep deleted**

it showed one file like this:

[image]

Now My doubt is, that this is the file that is eating the 15G thing and I think if I delete this, I will be able to get 15G ,  now there are two questions ?

1. Is my thinking is right?
2. If No, then what is the thing that is eating 15G and
3. If yes, then how to get that 15G back?

Comment: The image is so tiny that it is unreadable. And you should have pasted the text.

Comment: Right click the image and open in new tab, its pretty much visible :)

Answer (score 1):

Some process is still having an open [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) to the deleted huge file. So the resource would be released by the kernel only when there is no file descriptors to it (e.g. the using process closes the file descriptor or terminates). Read about [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) and [file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)